# Attach items to email based on delimited paths in a string

Tags: vba

I want to attach two files to an Outlook email.

I am trying to use `InStr`.

My For loop counts the files listed in an Excel cell, and attempts to attach the files that are separated by `;`

```
If Range(ColumnNumberToLetter(indexfiles) & ref_row).Value <> "" Then
    file_name = Sheets("Emails Management").Range(ColumnNumberToLetter(indexfiles) & ref_row).Value
                                 
    file_count = Len(file_name) - Len(Replace(file_name, ";", "")) + 1

    For Count = 1 To file_count
        file_search = InStr(1, file_name, ";")

        If file_search = 0 Then
            attach_name = RTrim(LTrim(file_name))
        Else
            attach_name = RTrim(LTrim(Left(file_name, file_search - 1)))
        End If

        .attachments.Add attach_name
    Next Count
                    
End If
```

In my cell I have :

```
="\\stack\over\flow "&Regular!E1&" -ByBusiness.pdf ; \\stack\over\flow "&Regular!E1&" -ByRegion.pdf"
```

My result is attaching the "ByBusiness" pdf to my email twice.

Is there a better way to attach multiple attachments?

Comment: Personally, I would use the `Split` function, that turns it into an array that you can parse easily.

Comment: Do you know how I could use `Split` in this loop?

Comment: looks like someone already showed you how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
pdfArray = Split("tes;tesds;astadsf;asdg", ";")
For Count = 0 To UBound(pdfArray)
     .attachments.Add pdfArray(Count)
Next Count
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it and now only adds the ByBusiness file and not the ByRegion file. I pass `file_name` into split.

Comment: What does debug.print(file_name) return to the immediate window?

Comment: It prints out the full line `="\\stack\over\flow "&Regular!E1&" -ByBusiness.pdf ; \\stack\over\flow "&Regular!E1&" -ByRegion.pdf"` but only append the first one before the email.

Comment: My expectation is that debug.print(file_name) is going to return to the immediate window a the resolved text value, not the formula. Change 
```.attachments.Add pdfArray(Count) ``` to ```debug.print(pdfArray(Count))``` and lets make sure you are printing 2 results.

Comment: Sorry it returns a text value, not a formula. It was returning the result of the formula. `\\stack\over\flow\Jul 02\-ByBusiness.pdf ; \\stack\over\flow\Jul 02\-ByRegion.pdf` . Now with your change in above comment it is returnings, Now with only `debug.print(pdfArray(Count))` it is outputting `\\stack\over\flow\Jul 02\-ByBusiness.pdf`

Comment: So its only print 1? Lets try hard coding it first and lets make sure its working there. I would make sure there is no spaces between the ";" so "\\stack\over\flow\Jul 02\-ByBusiness.pdf;\\stack\over\flow\Jul 02\-ByRegion.pdf". And then lets try hard coding it.
```
 pdfArray = Split("\\stack\over\flow\Jul 02\-ByBusiness.pdf ; \\stack\over\flow\Jul 02\-ByRegion.pdf", ";")
    For Count = 0 To UBound(pdfArray)
        .attachments.Add pdfArray(Count)
         Debug.Print (pdfArray(Count))
    Next Count
```

Comment: Hey! seems like getting rid of the space between two files worked!